# Disable ALL indexes on a table in SQL Server without Warning messages

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Occasionally we need to perform bulk updates on certain tables and the indexes that help the database perform smoothly in normal use become a hindrance. So we disable all the indexes on such a table, perform the update and then re-enable them afterward. To disable all the indexes on a table "x" we run the t-sql statement:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON x DISABLE
```

This results in a whole bunch of warnings like:

*Warning: Index 'y' on table 'x' was disabled as a result of disabling the clustered index on the table.*

Which is fair enough but we know what we're doing so these warnings are just noise.

**Is it possible to add something, similar to the NO_INFOMSGS parameter on the DBCC command, to suppress these unwanted warnings?**

Comment: How do you "perform the update" if the CI is disabled? Should see error `The query processor is unable to produce a plan because the index 'Foo' on table or view 'x' is disabled.`

Comment: I would *guess* (hope?) that the OP is `REBUILD`ing the clustered index before they `UPDATE` the table, @MartinSmith . If not, then we certainly don't have the full story here. Though if that's the case then presumably they're using dynamic SQL to create the batch, and if that's the case, then the "better" solution would seem to be that instead of using `ALL`, they `DISABLE` all the indexes *apart* from the `CLUSTERED` index. They could, if they wanted, still use `ALL` for the final `REBUILD` or again, just rebuild the disabled ones.

Comment: Does it *matter* if you get warnings? The warnings have a low severity so are not classed as errors.

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot disable this warning.

But if you want you could build a dynamic SQL string that disables the indexes in order, clustered index last.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(
  'ALTER INDEX ' + i.name + ' ON t DISABLE;',
  '
' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY i.index_id DESC)
FROM sys.indexes i
JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = i.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE t.name = 't'
  AND s.name = 'dbo';

PRINT @sql;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/cCaHvOan)

This is obviously much more complicated, and probably not worth it.